# Capturing error messages in html page using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex

I'm using Nodejs to check if there are some errors/warnings/notices generated by php in an html file.

The first thing I'm doing is to capture these errors using this regex on the body tag:

`const warningAndError = /(?:(?:.*\n){0,0}).*?<b>(Warning|Error|Notice)<\/b>.*(?:(?:\n.*))/gm;`

This will return a list like this :

```
["Error:  Here goes the err message on line 571",
 "Warning:  Here goes the warn message on line 700"]
```

What I want to do next is to create an array like this :

```
[chalk.red.bold("Error: ") + "Here goes the err message on line 571",
 chalk.yellow.bold("Warning: ") + "Here goes the warn message on line 700"]
```

So my code looks like this:

```
const warningAndError = /(?:(?:.*\n){0,0}).*?<b>(Warning|Error|Notice)<\/b>.*(?:(?:\n.*){0,0})/gm;
const errList = [];
(body.match(warningAndError) || []).forEach((err) => {
  let strippedString = err.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");

  if (strippedString.startsWith("Error:")) {
    errList.push(
      chalk.red.bold("Error: ") + strippedString.replace("Error:", "").trim()
    );
  }
  if (strippedString.startsWith("Warning:")) {
    errList.push(
      chalk.yellow.bold("Warning: ") + strippedString.replace("Warning:", "").trim()
    );
  }
  if (strippedString.startsWith("Notice:")) {
    errList.push(
      chalk.green.bold("Notice: ") + strippedString.replace("Notice:", "").trim()
    );
  }
});
```

The issue I'm having is that this is not clean, so I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it, and another thing is that it takes a long time to be executed more than 2 seconds.

If this will help, here is how the errors look in the html page:

```html
    <br />
<b>Error</b>:  Here goes the err message on line <b>571</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Here goes the warn message on line <b>700</b><br />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `{0,0}` supposed to do?

Comment: @xehpuk if I don'd do the first `{0,0}` it will return me the `<br />` so to not capture the line before the error line

Comment: `x{0,0}` means "repeat x zero times", so it's the same as an empty string. Your current regex could be simplified to `/.*?<b>(Warning|Error|Notice)<\/b>.*/gm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`RegExp.prototype.exec(String)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) should do the trick:

```js
const levels = {
  Error: 'red',
  Warning: 'yellow',
  Notice: 'green'
}

const regex = new RegExp(`<b>(${Object.keys(levels).join('|')})</b>:  ([^<]*)<b>([^<]*)`, 'g')

function chalkify(html) {
  const matches = []

  let match
  while ((match = regex.exec(html)) !== null) {
    const [ , level, message, line ] = match
    matches.push(chalk[levels[level]].bold(`${level}: `) + message + line)
  }

  regex.lastIndex = 0 // reset for next invocation

  return matches
}

// "Polyfill" and test in the browser:

const chalk = {
  red: { bold: _ => `<font color="red"><b>${_}</b></font>` },
  yellow: { bold: _ => `<font color="yellow"><b>${_}</b></font>` },
  green: { bold: _ => `<font color="green"><b>${_}</b></font>` }
}

document.body.innerHTML = chalkify(document.body.innerHTML).join('<br>')
```

```html
    <br />
<b>Error</b>:  Here goes the err message on line <b>571</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Here goes the warn message on line <b>700</b><br />
```

You could also use [`String.prototype.matchAll(RegExp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) if you're at least on [Node.js 12](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-String-prototype-matchAll).